# How to fix ''couldn't match expected type IO a0 with int'' in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, command-line, command-line-arguments

The line `checkArgCount args` gives me the trouble. `args` is a type `[String]` isn't it? I'm confused over why it gives me error.

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
import System.Environment --for command line args

--Checks if number of arguments provided is 2
checkArgCount ::[String] -> Int
checkArgCount a = if (length a) == 2 then 2 else error "No arguments" 

main :: IO()
main = do
     args <- getArgs
     checkArgCount args
```

Comment: Note that when there are two arguments, your code simplifies to `do args <- getArgs ; 2` where the 2 is the result of `checkArgCount args`. But `2` does not make sense inside the `do`, since it's not an action to be performed. Indeed, that's the issue. In my view, `checkArgCount` has the wrong type: why should checking something return an int?

Comment: `return $ checkArgCount args`, but in real code, `checkArgCount args` isn't going to be the last thing you call, so you probably want to do something else with the return value of `checkArgCount`.

Comment: `do` notation can be confuse when you starting, in case you not already know, the wiki have a good [page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
args <- getArgs
     if (length args) /= 2
        then return()
        else do -- ..continue coding
```

Proved to be far simpler solution

Comment: Consider using `System.Exit.die` or something similar instead of `return ()`.

Answer (score 3):

`main` is declared to have the type `IO ()` (which is correct). The last expression in any function is the return value. This particular code returns the result of `checkArgCount args`, which is `Int`.

An `Int` value isn't an `IO ()` value, so that doesn't type check.

You should either change the type of `checkArgCount` to return `()` or `IO ()`, or add more code to `main` that uses the `Int` returned by `checkArgCount`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `args :: [String]`, but `checkArgCount args` must have type `IO ()`, being the last line in the `do` block with the overall type `IO ()`.

So it's about the output type, not the input type of that function.

Changing `2` to `print 2` in the `if`'s consequent should fix it (and of course changing the type signature of `checkArgCount` to fit the change).